# Rails: Translation in Initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, initializer

I have several translations tucked away into an initializer like so:

```
GROUP_GOVERNANCE_STYLES = [
  [I18n.t("constants.group_governance_styles.collective"), 1],
  [I18n.t("constants.group_governance_styles.electoral_democracy"), 2],
  [I18n.t("constants.group_governance_styles.dictatorship"), 3]
]
```

In my en.yml file I have:

```
en:
  constants:
    group_governance_styles:
      collective: "collective"
      electoral_democracy: "electoral democracy"
      dictatorship: "dictatorship"
```

Unfortunately, when I try to render these translations in a view, I get the following errors:

```
translation missing: en.constants.group_governance_styles.collective
translation missing: en.constants.group_governance_styles.electoral_democracy
translation missing: en.constants.group_governance_styles.dictatorship
```

I've also tried removing the scope, but the translations still come up as missing. Is there another way to approach this? Perhaps there's a default scope for initializers that I don't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, translations get loaded after the initializers. Try putting it in environment.rb

Comment: This works! I don't know much about environment.rb, but it seems like it might be a bad practice to fill it with constants like this one. Would it be possible to load a file containing the constants from within environment.rb?

Comment: Agreed. I'm not a big fan of adding code to environment.rb either. You can also put that code in a separate file (maybe in the lib folder?) and require that file in environment.rb.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to use your translation files in other initializer files you can add an `I18n` initializer.

*config/initializers/i18n.rb*

```
# Load application custom translations in order to use them in other initializers
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Comment: Works like a charm and is clean :) Thanks.